# How to get Slurpable data from REST client in Groovy?

Tags: json, rest, groovy

I have code that looks like this:

```
def client = new groovyx.net.http.RESTClient('myRestFulURL')

def json = client.get(contentType: JSON) 
net.sf.json.JSON jsonData = json.data as net.sf.json.JSON   
def slurper = new JsonSlurper().parseText(jsonData)
```

However, it doesn't work! :(  The code above gives an error in parseText because the json elements are not quoted.  The overriding issue is that the "data" is coming back as a Map, not as real Json.  Not shown, but my first attempt, I just passed the parseText(json.data) which gives an error about not being able to parse a HashMap.

So my question is: how do I get JSON returned from the RESTClient to be parsed by JsonSlurper?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [RESTClient](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/RESTClient.html) class automatically parses the content and it doesn't seem possible to keep it from doing so.

However, if you use [HTTPBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/HTTPBuilder.html) you can overload the behavior. You want to get the information back as text, but if you only set the `contentType` as `TEXT`, it won't work, since the `HTTPBuilder` uses the `contentType` parameter of the [HTTPBuilder.get()](http://groovy.codehaus.org/modules/http-builder/apidocs/groovyx/net/http/HTTPBuilder.html#get(java.util.Map)) method to determine both the `Accept` HTTP Header to send, as well was the parsing to do on the object which is returned. In this case, you need `application/json` in the `Accept` header, but you want the parsing for `TEXT` (that is, no parsing).

The way you get around that is to set the `Accept` header on the `HTTPBuilder` object before calling `get()` on it. That overrides the header that would otherwise be set on it. The below code runs for me.

```
@Grab(group='org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder', module='http-builder', version='0.6')
import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.TEXT

def client = new groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder('myRestFulURL')
client.setHeaders(Accept: 'application/json')

def json = client.get(contentType: TEXT)
def slurper = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parse(json)
```

Comment: This only works perfectly!  Thanks!  I will say that when I converted I missed the change to "parse" from "parseText".  The "json" variable above is really a StringReader, so "parse" is the required method.

Comment: Looks like a nice workaround, but isn't anyone curious as to why RESTClient returns a hashmap when the response is JSON ??? I'm getting the same thing and I'd like to understand why it's returning a hashmap, and how to convert this to JSON (if this is not a bug)

Comment: I understand now, I will post another solution

Comment: It seems kind of contradictory/pessimistic to set the request header `client.setHeaders(Accept: 'application/json')` but then override the  response header `def json = client.get(contentType: TEXT)` eh? Well-behaved servers should respect the "Accept" header, and mis-behaved ones will need an override. And yes, @Marc, it is a common bungle to conflate JSON and Maps.

Answer (score 2):

The type of response from RESTClient will depend on the version of :

`org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder`

For example, with version `0.5.2`, i was getting a `net.sf.json.JSONObject` back.

In version `0.7.1`, it now returns a HashMap as per the question's observations.

When it's a map, you can simply access the JSON data using the normal map operations :

`def jsonMap = restClientResponse.getData()
def user = jsonMap.get("user")
....`

Answer (score 1):

Solution posted by jesseplymale workes for me, too.

HttpBuilder has dependencies to some appache libs,
so to avoid to add this dependencies to your project,
you can take this solution without making use of HttpBuilder:

```
def jsonSlurperRequest(urlString) {
    def url = new URL(urlString)
    def connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection()
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET")
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json")
    connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0")
    new JsonSlurper().parse(connection.getInputStream())
}
```

Comment: However, if you need to support going through a Proxy Server, you will be far better off with HttpBuilder....